# Delete every four rows in excel

Tags: excel, vba

Very new to VBA but have experience in some other languages but need help with this one. I'm trying to create a macro that deletes every 4 rows. For example leave row 1 but delete 2,3,4,5 skip 6 and continue on. This is what I have so far:

```
Sub Macro1()

For x = 100 To 1 Step -2
    Range(x & ":" & x).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
Next x
End Sub
```

I'm not sure if my For loop is missing something or maybe i need some sort of index counter to tell it to delete four at a time.

Comment: you are taking steps of two so every other row. You can use resize to get a group of four rows. You are looping backwards which is good. ClearContents is not the same as Delete. You are clearing the cell contents.

Comment: Using .Select is very inefficient. Determine what all the numbers are that you will delete and then delete in one go. You can employ mod function , to determine row stays or goes, perhaps in its own function that returns a boolean saying whether to add to the union range for deletion. You can have them as an array of ranges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will start at row 100 and step backwards to row 1.

```
Sub remove_rows()
Dim x As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For x = 100 To 1 Step -5
    Range(x & ":" & x - 3).EntireRow.Delete
Next x

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

(I have the `.Select` in this .gif just to show you visually. You don't want that in the actual macro as it can slow it down):
[image]

Edit: Ah, I noticed I delete the row. You can just replace `.EntireRow.Delete` with `.EntireRow.ClearContents` and it'll just clear the contents without deleting the row itself.

Comment: I bow before your excel skills, but more-so your stackoverflow wizardry, Batman. Bravo sir.

Comment: I really appreciate the help, I get how it works for the most part dont quite understand the range part. I take it x is the whole sheet but how does x -3 effect how the For loop functions. Also I can use either .Clearcontents or .Delete that was bad use of terms on my part in the original post, it is a very large data set ~2000 values so I will most likely stay with the .delete .

Comment: @gShaw - The `x-3` in the `Range()` does *not* affect the `For loop`. All we're doing is telling VBA to start in row 100.  Then select row `100`, `99`,`98`, and `97` and delete.  The `x : x-3` is essentially a block of FOUR rows.  We just want to move this four row block up 5 rows, skipping the row to keep.    Step through the macro with `F8`, and you can watch it go line-by line (that's what I did in my .gif). (Add in the `.Select` to see it select the row before it deletes it).

Comment: @BruceWayne - I gotcha now, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @gShaw - Did this answer work for you? If so, you can mark it as the Answer (click the check mark left of the post, below the down arrow). This will also remove it from the Unanswered Question queue.  Cheers!