# delete every n rows in excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I have a data set in excel with measurements taken every 15 minutes (one measurement one row), where I would like to keep only the ones taken on a full hour and delete the rest. In other words: I would like to keep the first row, delete the next three, keep the 5th row, delete the next three and so on.
I would like to use VBA but I'm completely new to this.
I've found this macro here, which deletes every four rows

```
Sub remove_rows()
Dim x As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For x = 100 To 1 Step -5
    Range(x & ":" & x - 3).EntireRow.Delete
Next x

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

(Source: [Delete every four rows in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48813698/delete-every-four-rows-in-excel))
How do I change it to delete only every three rows? I have to do the same with a dataset with measurements taken every 5 minutes (keep the 1 row, delete the next eleven, keep the 12th and so on). Is this macro good for this dataset as well? And lastly - is using VBA the best solution for this problem or is there another method which is better? The datasets are fairly big (100k+ rows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powerquery (2016 in the data tab > Get and Transform, 2013 free add-in from microsoft then powerquery tab) is ***absolutely*** optimized for this sort of operation over the number of rows you mention. It takes < 1 minute to write the query.

```
.66 of a second on a test with 200K rows to complete task.
```

1) Select row in data, then data > from table

[image: Data]

2) Indicate whether you table has headers

[image: Headers]

3)  Query editor screen pops up

[image: Query editor]

4) Select Home > Remove rows > Remove alternate row

[image: Remove rows]

5) Specify pattern. For example, keep 1 remove 3 as in your example:

[image: Pattern]

6) Hit Ok. Observe new pattern fits requirement

[image: Result]

7) Home > Close and Load >

[image: Close and load]

8) Specify where to close and load to e.g. new sheet

[image: Location]

You can load to same sheet or new sheet. Bingo you have your new data set. Anytime you add rows to your original dataset you can simply refresh this query and the result set will update removing the unwanted rows.

Output:

[image: Output]

Refresh query (green circling arrows):

1) Next to workbook query itself

[image: Refresh1]

2) Or from ribbon > Refresh

[image: Refresh2]

Answer (score 0):

I think the code above is a little dangerous and will require tweaking for a different total number of rows.  You could modify as follows:

```
For x = 100 To 1 Step -4
    Range(x & ":" & x - 2).EntireRow.Delete
Next x
```

But you have to make sure you're starting at the right place and preserving the right cells.  The Step -4 steps back four cells at a time, then the following line deletes row x, x-1, and x-2.

Why not just create a column that indicates whether the observation ends at an hour, then sort the list by that column and delete everything after the transition point?  It's less automated, but also less likely to cause a problem.

If you really wanted to go the VBA route, I'd check in the code to ensure the observation is hourly and only then delete.  I'm not big into trusting my data, though.

Answer (score 0):

1st version bellow (`AutoFilter`) is very fast - 2 seconds, for 100 K rows

To change the row interval, update the `4` in `Const FRM` (formula)

---

.

**Version 1** - using an **`AuroFilter`**

```
Option Explicit

'Deleted Rows: 75,000 (out of 100,000) - Time:  2.341 sec

Public Sub DeleteRowSetsAutoFilter()

    Const FRM = "=MOD(ROW() - 1, 4) = 0"        'Rows where reminder of Row/4 = 0

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, wsName As String, fc As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
    Set ws2 = Sheets.Add(After:=ws1)            'Add new sheet
    wsName = ws1.Name

    Set fc = ws1.UsedRange.Columns(ws1.UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1) 'Filter column
    fc.Formula = FRM
    fc.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="TRUE"   'Rows to be deleted: 2 To 4, 6 To 8, ...

    ws1.UsedRange.Copy                          'Copy visible rows to new sheet
    ws2.Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    ws2.Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll           'Paste data on new sheet

    ws1.Delete                                  'Delete old sheet
    ws2.Name = wsName
    ws2.Cells(1).Select
    ws2.Columns(ws2.UsedRange.Columns.Count).EntireColumn.Delete  'Delete filter column

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

---

.

**Version 2** - using a `For` loop

```
Public Sub DeleteRowSetsForLoop()

    Const STP = 4    'Row interval

    Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long, i As Long, toDel As Range

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set toDel = ws.Rows(lr + 1) 'First empty row (just to set the range)

    For i = 1 To lr Step STP
        Set toDel = Union(toDel, ws.Rows(i + 1 & ":" & i + (STP - 1))) '2-4, 6-8, etc.
    Next

    toDel.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

---

.

```
Rows: 2,500  (out of 10 K)

DeleteRowSetsAutoFilter() - Time: 0.085 sec, 0.086 sec, 0.089 sec
DeleteRowSetsForLoop()    - Time: 9.568 sec, 9.524 sec, 9.530 sec
```